# APK Expansion Download Test Error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, download, apk-expansion-files

I am currently working on APK expansion file by referring to the example from here http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
But, I am stuck at "Testing file downloads". I did exactly what it told me to do but when I run my app, it just stuck at the downloading UI screen with 0MB/0MB.

I did set the BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY the same as in my GooglePlay publisher account.
I did upload both APK and the expansion file on GooglePlay as Beta and a draft.
And I am running the app through eclipse which builds the app into my android device.

So did I miss something else?
Do I need to provide some kind of URL? if so how do I get the URL and where to set it?

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks.